# MariaDB в XAMPP

Tags: mariadb

В новых дистрибутивах иксампа входит MariaDB,поясните пожалуйста в чем разница? Есть ли существенные отличия с Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в кратце, то разницы(для разработчика) нет.

**MariaDB** это форк **MySQL**. Небольшие отличия есть, но обычного разработчика это врятли коснётся.

У MariaDB более открытое сообшество и управление проэктом и лучше(свободнее) лицензия. А MySQL владеет Oracle и есть модули/части с закрытым кодом... По этому, открытому сообшеству больше импонирует MariaDB.

Самое заметное отличае(для разработчика) вместо движка `InnoDB` используеться `XtraDB`. Опять для разработчика разницы не будет.

Сравнение функционала.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/

Несовместимости.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/